# Software for video trimming and/or mkv to mp4 converting without any quality loss

Tags: windows, video, video-editing, media-converter

I'm looking for two programs (or one that does both). Firstly i want to cut video without any quality loss. It has to be the same video as before but without cutted parts. I have tried avidemux but it lets you cut in specific parts which is very inaccurate. HandBrake gives you more freedom, but you can't choose milliseconds which is quite inaccurate too.

And i want to convert mkv video to mp4. The same as before, without any quality loss, it has to be the same video, but mp4.

It can be paid software as long as it does what it should.

Answer (score 3):

I would just use [FFMPEG](http://ffmpeg.org/):

- Free, **Gratis** & Open Source
- Cross Platform - Runs on just about everything
- Cut & join mkv without loss of quality, just supply the start time(s) and duration for each section and specify that the settings be copied to avoid re-coding.
- Convert mkv to mp4 without loss of quality *there will always be some change in quality if you re-encode* but `ffmpeg -i input.mkv -codec copy output.mp4` will avoid re-coding.
- **Fast** depending on your system the above command could process a 1 hour mkv to mp4 in about 1 minute.

Comment: Ok, so resolution and "visible quality" will stay the same?

Comment: @CorporalGirrafe __If__ you use the `-codec copy` and don't ask for any changes in resolution or quality there will be no change of resolution or quality. However, you _may_ get some change in quality around each cut as your cut points may not be key frames.

Comment: Then it's not an option, because in the end video is visibly different.

Comment: @CorporalGirrafe did you notice the __may__ and __some__ change in quality - if you find a noticeable difference you can vary the times fractionally, (to hit the keyframes) and the problem will go away.

Comment: Ffmpeg is the best thing it there when it comes to multimedia creation, conversion etc

Comment: @CorporalGirrafe there's no way to freely cut at any position without any re-encode, because videos are split into [GOPs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_of_pictures) which are encoded separately and if you split in the middle of the GOP you must create a new GOP which require a re-encode. Avidemux also offers the same copy stream option if you split at the GOP boundaries

Comment: You can copy without reencode? WQow

Comment: @user4951 that's what 'copy' means, it literally means 'no encoding'.

Answer (score 0):

Try [video4web](http://www.moyeamedia.com/video-to-flash) by Moyea. Pretty helpful. You can convert from avi, mkv, mov. You can also edit from the same software [ crop, trim, watermark] among others. I use it to convert most of my Raw videos. I'd definitely recommend. Plus it is free.

Comment: The important thing is does it convert *without any quality loss*? I think no.